# How to delete a session in cgi-perl?

Tags: perl, session

I have a perl-cgi script through which I am trying to log in.

When the UserName and password are valid, I create a session and redirect a cookie to another page.

However, after the session expires(I have set the expiration time), I do not see it get deleted from the /tmp/sessions folder in this case. I have used the command to delete the session as well.

Can someone help me to delete the session once it expires? Also, does the cookie expire once the session is deleted?

```
        use CGI::Session;
        use CGI::Session::Tutorial;
        use CGI::Session::Driver::file; 
        use CGI::Cookie;

        my $session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, {Directory=>"/tmp/sessions"});         
        my $sid = $session->id();           
        #my $cookie = $query->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
        my $cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>"CGISESSID",
                        -value=>$session->id,
                        -domain=>'abc.com',
                        -expires=>"+5m",
                        -path=>"/");

        print $query->redirect(-uri => 'http://abc.cgi', -cookie => $cookie);
        $session->param("UserName", $loginUserName);
        $query->hidden( 'UserName', $loginUserName );

        $session->expire("UserName",'1m');
        $session->expire('+5m'); 
        $session->delete();
```

Comment: This is definitely not a [mcve] - all this code does is create a session and then deletes it.

Comment: I want it to delete once the session expires.

Answer (score 4):

*To avoid confusion with `->delete`, I'm going to use the word "remove" instead of "delete" to refer to the removal of the session from storage.*

---

> *Can someone help me to delete the session once it expires?*

The removal doesn't happen when the session expires. That would require having a continually running process. Furthermore, at no point does CGI::Session scan storage for expired sessions; that would take too long since it would require loading each and every session. Instead, **CGI::Session only removes expired sessions when you try to load them.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

use CGI::Session               qw( );
use CGI::Session::Driver::file qw( );

my $session_id;   # This represents the browser's cookie.

# These represent requests made the by the browser.
for my $request_num (1..3) {
   my $session = CGI::Session->new("driver:file", $session_id, { Directory => "/tmp/sessions" });
   $session->expire("1s");
   $session_id = $session->id;  # This represents setting the browser's cookie.

   say "$request_num: ", $session->id;
   say "$request_num: ", $session->param("foo") // "[undef]";
   $session->param("foo" => "bar");

   # This represents time passing by before the third request.
   if ($request_num == 2) {
      say "Letting session expire...";
      sleep(2);
   }   
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a
1: c57ab28952c6ed422c15f1a223f4b45d
1: [undef]
2: c57ab28952c6ed422c15f1a223f4b45d
2: bar
Letting session expire...
3: df8ba3b66f23a9a2a652520fa6b4c30b
3: [undef]

$ ls -1 /tmp/sessions
cgisess_df8ba3b66f23a9a2a652520fa6b4c30b
```

**If you want to prevent files from accumulating on your drive**, create a `cron`  job that deletes old files.

```
find /tmp/sessions -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime 7 -delete
```

---

> *Also, does the cookie expire once the session is deleted?*

No, the cookie expires when you tell it to expire. The thing is, it doesn't matter if the browser's cookie expires or not. **For the second argument of `new`, there's no difference between passing `undef`, passing the id of a deleted session and passing the id of an expired session**; you'll get a new session in all three cases. If anything, it's actually better if it doesn't expire as soon as the session expires because this allows the session to be removed (as demonstrated above).

---

> *How to delete a session in cgi-perl?*

`$session->delete` is indeed the way to go, but the actual removal only happens when you would save (flush) the session.

```
$session->delete();
$session->flush();  # Or let `$session` get destroyed.
```

Comment: Since we're being nitpicky today, this answer contradicts itself, first saying that "**CGI::Session only deletes expired sessions when you try to load them.**" (emphasis in original), then later saying that it deletes them "when you would save the session", which does not involve trying to load the session.

Comment: So I only imagined the last sentence of non-code text saying "the actual deletion only happens when you would save the session."? It's deleted _only_ when the session is loaded... and also deleted _only_ when the session would be saved...  Those two "only"s cannot be simultaneously true.

Comment: Expired sessions are removed on load (when using `->new`). Sessions for which `->delete` has been called are removed on save. Both of these can be true simultaneously.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman, Altered wording of the answer to help avoid confusion.

Comment: @ikegami could you provide me an example for the same? What do you mean by "Expired sessions are removed on load (when using ->new)." When you use "load", you don't use "new" right?Since load will create a session if it has expired as mentioned previously.

Comment: If you use `load` to load an expired session, the returned session object will have been flagged as deleted (as if you have called `->delete`) and will be unusable (so you have to check if it's deleted before using it). The session will get removed from storage when the object is flushed. /// Re "*Since load will create a session if it has expired as mentioned previously.*", You have it backwards. `new` is the one that creates a new session if provided id refers to an expired (or non-existent) session. That's why `new` is far more convenient to use in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation notes](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#delete())

> **`delete()`**
>
> *Sets the objects status to be "deleted"*. Subsequent read/write requests on the same object will fail. ***To physically delete it from the data store you need to call `flush()`***. `CGI::Session` attempts to do this automatically when the object is being destroyed (usually as the script exits), but see "A Warning about Auto-flushing". (*emphases mine*)

You go on to ask:

> Also, does the cookie expire once the session is deleted?

Of course not. You already sent a cookie to the user's browser with an expiration time of five minutes in the future. The cookie will expire then.

If, in the mean time, you have forced the expiration of the session on the server, the user's browser will still send the previously received cookie. Your application will just not find a session corresponding to the session identifier stored in the cookie.

You *really* need to understand the HTTP request/response cycle before taking one more step.

Comment: How does this answer "*Can someone help me to delete the session once it expires?*"

Answer (score 0):

Per [the CGI::Session documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#delete()), `delete`ing a session *"Sets the objects status to be "deleted". Subsequent read/write requests on the same object will fail. **To physically delete it from the data store you need to call flush().**"* (emphasis mine)

Also, per [the CGI::Session::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Tutorial#EXPIRATION), *"Expiring a session is the same as deleting it via delete(), but deletion takes place automatically."*  It is not necessary (or useful) to `delete` a session after it has expired.

Comment: @ikagami: 1) It shows that, in CGI::Session, "expire" and "delete" are synonymous. An expired session _is already_ deleted, in the sense of the `delete` method. 2) What the OP actually appears to want is to delete the session file from the disk, which the answer indicates is accomplished by calling the `flush` method, not the `delete` method.

Comment: Re: "expire" vs. "delete", yeah, I should have said that "expire**d**" and "delete**d**" are synonymous. Unless you mean to say that the documentation is incorrect when it claims that the only difference between expiring and deleting a session is when it gets deleted?

Comment: OK, so you *are* claiming that the documentation is wrong when it says "**Expiring a session is the same as deleting it** via delete(), but deletion takes place automatically." I have no responsibility for that alleged error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151635/discussion-between-dave-sherohman-and-ikegami).

Comment: Your answer does not help the OP remove expired session from the disk in the least, even though that's what they asked about.