# How to set cookie expiration time in CGI::Session?

Tags: perl, session

If a new session is created when I log in and a cookie is created too. Everytime I perform an activity in another page, I have written code to increase the session time by 10 minutes. However, after 10 min of the last activity performed, the session will expire(if idle) but it will be created from the cookieID.

Login Page:
If credentials are valid->

```
        my $session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, {Directory=>"/tmp/sessions"});         
        my $sid = $session->id();           
        $page = 'page1'; 

        my $cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>"CGISESSID",
                        -value=>$session->id,
                        -domain=>'test.com',
                        path=>"/");
        print "Set-Cookie: $cookie\n";  
         $session->expire('+10m');
```

Page1:(When page1 loads or any activity is performed in page 1)

```
    my $cookieSid = $query->cookie("CGISESSID") || undef;
    my $session;
    $session    = CGI::Session->load(undef, $cookieSid, 
    {Directory=>'/tmp/sessions'});
    $session->expire('+10m');
    my $cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>"CGISESSID",
                                -value=>$session->id,
                                 -path=>"/");
    print "Set-Cookie: $cookie\n";
```

I have set the cookie to expire when the browser is closed. In case when the session expires I want to redirect to the login page. But the above code  will keep initializing sessions with the same cookieID. What should be the cookie expiry time in this case?

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: You can just add an `-expires => '+10m'` to the cookie as well. It will be resent in every request.

Comment: Also, when the session expires how do I delete the session from the folder. I do not clearly understand the meaning of flush()

Comment: Why do you need the cookie to expire? Why don't you just delete it when the session is no longer valid?

Comment: Using `->load` without checking if you have a valid session is bad. You should use `->new` instead since it handles all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `->load` without checking if you have a valid session is bad. You should use `->new` instead since it handles all that for you. Both pages should use

```
# Get session id if any.
my $sid = $query->cookie("CGISESSID");

# Load or create session.
my $session = CGI::Session->new("driver:file", $sid, { Directory => "/tmp/sessions" });
$session->expire('+10m');

# Update $sid since session id may have changed.
$sid = $session->id();

my $cookie = $query->cookie(
   -name   => "CGISESSID",
   -value  => $id,
   -domain => 'test.com',
   -secure => $ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} =~ /s\z/i ? 1 : 0,
   -path   => "/",
);
print "Set-Cookie: $cookie\n";
```

When someone logs in, you do something like

```
$session->param( user => $user );
```

When you want to check if someone is logged in, you can use

```
if (defined($session->param('user'))) { ... }
```

---

Now, you asked how to cause the cookie to expire. This is done using

```
-expires => "+10m"
```

But I wouldn't do that. Since expired sessions are removed from storage on load, it good to be provided session id to expired sessions. This won't happen if you expire the cookie at the same time as the session.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Does this take care of deleting expired sessions?

Comment: I did not understand "Since expired sessions are removed from storage on load, it good to be provided session id to expired sessions. This won't happen if you expire the cookie at the same time as the session."

Comment: 1)  I specifically recommended that you don't expire the cookie. 2) Even if you expire the cookie, that assumes everything works perfectly. Clients may not expired their cookies immediately, clocks could be out of sync, and data takes time to travel. 2) You are still misusing `->load` even if everything works perfectly.  3) Since you don't want any of the behaviour of `->load`, you shouldn't use `->load`.

Comment: as you said I am not using load, and following what you suggested. However, how do I delete the sessions once they expire from the directory? I believe load deletes expired sessions,but now how do I do it?

Comment: Already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45596233/589924) that: Create a cron job that deletes old files.

Answer (score 1):

You are already setting a new relative expire time for your session. Nothing stops you from doing that [for the cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#-expires) as well.

```
$session->expire('+10m');
my $cookie = $query->cookie(
    -name    => "CGISESSID",
    -value   => $session->id,
    -path    => "/",
    -expires => "+10m",
);
print "Set-Cookie: $cookie\n";
```

Since the cookie will be sent in every response header, the browser will just over-write it in its cookie jar every time.

Since you want both the cookie and the session to expire at the same time, you might want to make that a configuration value, and use a variable in place of the two `"+10m"` strings instead.

---

Also note that if the session has already been expired, a user coming back later should not be a problem. They might *reactivate* the old ID, but it will be a fresh session that just happens to have the same ID.

If you don't trust that, you can also [check if the session is expired](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#is_expired()) after loading it, and [delete it](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#delete()) if it has.

Comment: If I set the cookie expiration time to 10 min each time a new session gets created and a new cookie with a new ID respectively?

Comment: @ShivaniSarin I don't understand your question.